# Grails5 standalone: First browser hit takes longer

Tags: grails, sitemesh

Using Grails 5, I create web applications and let them package in a standalone runnable war/jar file using the Grails build command.

Since Grails5, every page load in browser takes quite longer (4-5x of the following requests) than the following ones (does not matter which data or query). Thus, it seems like that the time that‘s consumed is for building the GSP. I‘m using Ubuntu 20 LTS and the java -jar command to run it.

Is there a new caching system implemented?

Comment: " Thus, it seems like that the time that‘s consumed is for building the GSP." - That is only 1 explanation.  Have you profiled the app and verified that is where the time is being spent?

Comment: How would you recommend to proceed to profile it?

Comment: "How would you recommend to proceed to profile it?" - If you are asking for a tool recommendation, I would suggest YourKit.  If you are asking about how to use a profiler, that is more than would be appropriate to try and address here.

Comment: The answer to the original question posted above is "no", there is not a new caching system.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a new caching system implemented?

No, we didn't introduce a new caching system.